# How to replace values that have a specific character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, replace, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert multiple columns from varchar to money. Most values of these columns have the right syntax, but some of them have an 'E' (like this: '-1,42109E-14'). Because of that I get an error when I try to convert:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

I'm converting this way (and it works for other columns that don't have these specific values):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name money
```

So I thought about trying to replace values that has this 'E' with '0' (zero) and after that I can convert to money.

I can find these specific values with the following query:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%E%'
```

But I don't know how can I replace these specifics values with '0' (zeros). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can use `REPLACE()` function or `TRANSLATE()` as well.

Comment: `'-1,42109E-14'` is a floating point value. You would be better off changing the column to a `float` type first, and then `money`. Removing the `E` will **significantly** change the value.

Comment: Furthermore, money is not sufficient with -14

Comment: As an example `-1.42109E-14` is `-0.0000000000000142`. On the other hand, removing the `'E'` would become `'-1.42109-14'`. You would have to then use dynamic SQL to work out that value, which would come out to be `-15.42109`; that's nothing like the previous number.

Comment: Sami, thank you for you suggestion. I think the REPLACE() doesn't work in this case because this value is just an example. I have many others like that ('-7,10543E-15', '2,842171E-14', '9,094947E-13' etc.). To use REPLACE() I would have to specify each one of this values.

Comment: Larnu and John Cappelletti, thank you for your contribution. My ideia wasn't replace the 'E' with '0', but the entire value (I would replace '-1.42109E-14' with '0'; replace '9,094947E-13' with '0' and so on.

Comment: So @LedaGrasiele you can do it as `update tablename set column = '0' where try_cast(column as datatype) is null` Then change the datatype of your column.

Comment: That *could* be dangerous @Sami . What if the OP has values like `'1.23459E13'`?

Comment: It could be not @Larnu & if we follow `"what if"` then we're going to post an endless edits on our answers. Also in my example I just wrote `datatype` and let the OP choose.

Comment: Sami, well observed. I have other values that have the right syntax, like '1,00', '1352,10', '-791,65' etc.. Those one I can convert normally without any problem (my language setting is us_english, so decimal is separated by commas).

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comment, first change your column to a `float`, as the value you have is a floating point value:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name float;
```

*Note, this assumes your language setting is European based, which uses `,` as a decimal point. If not, this will fail.*

Then you should change the column type again. As John mentions, `money` isn't large enough in scale to store this (`money` has a scale of 4). if you *do* use money, the value would result in `0.00`. For the value you have, you probably want something like a `decimal(38,16)` (choose one suitable for you).

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name decimal(38,16);
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=18e5570454b2f69c1c9968f7ae9442dd)

Comment: Thank you again. Actually my language setting is portuguese. But I will try your suggestion with some changes (adapting it to my language). I think it will work.

Comment: If the server setting is Portuguese, then this will work, @LedaGrasiele . My note is saying it will fail if it isn't a European based language (i.e. English, British, Mexican (perhaps)).

Comment: I'm sorry, I said wrong. I checked here and edited the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I really apreciate all the answers and suggestions here. In the end, my problem was simpler than I imagined. I solved it with an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = '0' WHERE column_name LIKE '%E%';
```

I repeated this code for all columns with these problems.